# Error while parsing .PKB file

Tags: pmd

so I am trying to analyze a .pkb file from gitBash and I encountered this error:

[image]

Here is line 737 from the pkb:

```
        FOR sum_res IN (SELECT SUM(loss_reserve) loss_reserve,
                               SUM(expense_reserve) exp_reserve
                          FROM gicl_clm_reserve a, gicl_item_peril b
                         WHERE a.claim_id = b.claim_id
                           AND a.item_no  = b.item_no
                           AND a.peril_cd = b.peril_cd
                           AND a.claim_id = p_claim_id
                           AND (NVL(b.close_flag, 'AP') IN ('AP','CC','CP') OR 
                                NVL(b.close_flag2, 'AP') IN ('AP','CC','CP')))
        LOOP
           v_loss_res_amt  := sum_res.loss_reserve;
           v_exp_res_amt   := sum_res.exp_reserve;
        END LOOP;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I understood is that it wants me to put the FOR loop in a single line? Is there any workaround from this issue?

Comment: Hi there! I'm a PMD maintainer. You seem to have come across a bug. I've just added [an issue](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/681) to track it. I'd appreciate if you could comment there so we can follow this up with you as we work towards a fix. Thanks!

Comment: Hi John, already did, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt editing whitespaces would do any good here.

In general, it does not want anything from you. It crashed spectacularly because it was not able to analyze this SQL fragment. In SQL, use of whitespaces is rather loose, so parser should habe no problem in processing multi-line queries.

It failed when it read the "SUM" keyword, but as for why, no idea. Guessing by the stacktrace, `IsTypeOf`/`IsNullCondition`/`UnaryExpresion`, it probably expects something simpler at some place.

Judging by the error saying `SUM SUM`, maybe it expected the inner SELECT to return a single column and thus maybe it failed on noticing second `SUM` keyword and produced error `oops, I found SELECT SUM , SUM (..) in a single-value-query context`. Unfortunately, the exception message lacks details in that area.

Aside from waiting here for somebody with more experience in that subjeyc than me (and I have zero, I respond basing on my experience on static code analysis and the exception text you provided), I would send this as a bug ticket to the developers of the PLSQLParser class/module - for me, it really looks like a bug or notimplemented part of PL/SQL specification.

It also may be that the parser supports only some older version of the PL/SQL language and your file is written using a newer one. In that case it's not a bug, but rather, your bad luck and you'd need to change the toolset or wait until it's supported. Another option is that the analytic tool supports newer version of the language, but is set up to use the older one for some unknown reason. If so, then it may be just a matter of some extra configuration to be done.

Disclaimer: just to be clear, let me repeat, all of that is more-or-less educated guessing.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the suggestions. I agree, the exception message didn't give me anything solid on how to fix the error. I guess I have to wait for an answer from someone on the PMD team.